# How to make same http call on load and on keyup

Tags: angular, rxjs

In my application i have a modal with a list and an input search field. The modal is invoked on button click in parent component which calls the public function inside the modal component that fetches the list item.Also, whenever user types in the search bar, again the same http request is made to get all the data having the search value since all data has not been loaded at once.

For search input, i'm using subject which emits value on keyup.

```
public showModal(msg) {
  this.headMsg = msg;
  this.loadList();
}
```

```
loadList() {
  this.onListUpdate(this.getList(""));
}
```

```
getList(param: string) {
  this.loader = true;
  return this.httpService.getProducts(param);
}
```

```
onListUpdate(list$: Observable<any>) {
  list.subscribe((response: any[]) => {
    if(response) this.items = response;
  },
  error => console.log(error),
  () => this.loader = false
 )
}
```

input keyup

```
 this.filterChanged.next(searchTerm);
```

```
onSearchFieldChanged() {
    let item$ = this.filterChanged.pipe(
      debounceTime(this._debounceTime),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap(term => {
        return this.getList(term).pipe(
          tap(() => {
            this.loader = false;
          })
        );
      })
    )
    this.onListUpdate(item$);
  }
```

Is there a better way to handle the list update functionality?

Comment: It looks like you never unsubscribe from `item$`. I'd personally put `this.loader` elsewhere but that's just my preference.

Comment: You create too many suscriptions throughout your programs life. Please use only 1 subscription in ngOnInit using the filterChanged subject. Instead of loadList you send an empty string to that subject.

Answer (score 1):

**I  would improve the performance issue that you have.**

User can search the same thing a lot of times and in your case for the same string you are calling a new API, but the result will be the same.

**In this case, I recommend adding caching already used API with the same string.**

What we can do?

we can use `shareReplay` in combination with `Map` for your `getList` method.

I made an example of how it will look:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

import { mergeMap, exhaustMap, concatAll, shareReplay } from "rxjs/operators";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { from, Observable, Subject } from "rxjs";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  template: `
    <input
      type="number"
      min="1"
      max="10"
      (keyup)="onInputChange($event.target.value)"
    />
  `,
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  private readonly products = new Map<string, Observable<any>>();
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  ngOnInit() {}
  onInputChange(value) {
    console.log(value);
    this.getList(value).subscribe();
  }

  getList(param) {
    // this.loader = true;
    const cacheKey = param;
    if (!this.products.get(cacheKey)) {
      this.products.set(
        cacheKey,
        this.http
          .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/" + param)
          .pipe(shareReplay(1))
      );
    }

    return this.products.get(cacheKey);
  }
}
```

In accordance with the screeshot in your case, Based on your code you will have 7 API call!!!

In console, you can see set of user input `1, 12, 123, 12, 1, 12, 123`
You will have:

- two calls of API for - `1`
- two calls of - `123`
- and tree call of = `12`

Yes, I saw that you added `debounceTime` and `distinctUntillChanged` - but the issue still exists

**and we can reduce it to 3 unique  API calls**

[image]

So, Each searchable string we will store in Map as key, and API with `shareReaplay` (to avoid duplicate call API) as value.
And each time when we want call product we will check if API already exist in `Map` and if exist we will return the already used API

```
    if (!this.products.get(cacheKey)) {
      this.products.set(
        cacheKey,
        this.http
          .get(url + param)
          .pipe(shareReplay(1))
      );
    }

    return this.products.get(cacheKey);
```

You can try it in: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-rxjs-cz6pcs?file=src/app/app.component.ts